# Delete Index Entry in List (SML)

Tags: list, sml

I'm trying to write a function in ML to delete an entry from a list, given an index.

So, for example, if I have a list `L = [1,2,3,4,5]` and want to delete `3` from the list, I can call `delete(2, L)`, which should delete the element at index 2, which is 3.

I have a function for deleting from a list, given a specific item in the list, but was wondering how I could get an index from a list.

Below is my code from deleting a specific element from a list

```
fun delete(element, list_head::list_tail) =
          if element = list_head then list_tail
          else list_head::delete(element, list_tail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pattern matcher to define your two base cases and then implement your delete in terms of these cases.

```
fun delete (_,   nil) = nil
  | delete (0, _::xs) = xs
  | delete (i, x::xs) = x::del(i-1,xs);
```